# Issues with implementing a C++ file comparison program

Tags: c++, string, file, compare

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

// Function to remove spaces from a string
std::string removeSpaces(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result;
    std::remove_copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(result), ::isspace);
    return result;
}

// Function to find the position of the first difference in two strings
size_t findFirstDifference(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2, size_t& line1, size_t& column1, size_t& line2, size_t& column2) {
    size_t minSize = std::min(str1.size(), str2.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < minSize; ++i) {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i]) {
            size_t lineCount1 = std::count(str1.begin(), str1.begin() + i, '\n') + 1;
            size_t columnCount1 = i - str1.find_last_of('\n', i) + 1;

            size_t lineCount2 = std::count(str2.begin(), str2.begin() + i, '\n') + 1;
            size_t columnCount2 = i - str2.find_last_of('\n', i) + 1;

            line1 = lineCount1;
            column1 = columnCount1;
            line2 = lineCount2;
            column2 = columnCount2;

            return i;
        }
    }

    // If one string is longer than the other, return the position of the first extra character
    return minSize;
}

// Function to display the difference occurrence around a position
std::string displayDifferenceOccurrence(const std::string& str, size_t position) {
    size_t displayStart = (position > 10) ? (position - 10) : 0;
    size_t displayEnd = std::min(position + 50, str.size());
    return str.substr(displayStart, displayEnd - displayStart);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check if two file names are provided as command-line arguments
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <file1> <file2>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the first file
    std::ifstream file1(argv[1]);
    if (!file1.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening " << argv[1] << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the second file
    std::ifstream file2(argv[2]);
    if (!file2.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening " << argv[2] << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Read content of file1 into a string and remove spaces
    std::stringstream buffer1;
    buffer1 << file1.rdbuf();
    std::string content1 = removeSpaces(buffer1.str());

    // Read content of file2 into a string and remove spaces
    std::stringstream buffer2;
    buffer2 << file2.rdbuf();
    std::string content2 = removeSpaces(buffer2.str());

    // Find the position of the first difference
    size_t line1 = 1, column1 = 1, line2 = 1, column2 = 1;
    size_t firstDifference = findFirstDifference(content1, content2, line1, column1, line2, column2);

    // Compare the two strings
    if (firstDifference == content1.size() && firstDifference == content2.size()) {
        std::cout << "**********************************************************************************";
        std::cout << "\nThe contents of " << argv[1] << " and " << argv[2] << " are the same.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "**********************************************************************************";
        std::cout << "\nThe contents of " << argv[1] << " and " << argv[2] << " are different.\n";
        std::cout << "\nDifference at " << argv[1] << " line " << line1 << ", column " << column1 << "\n";

        // Display 20 characters where the error occurred in file1
        std::string displayContent1 = displayDifferenceOccurrence(content1, firstDifference);
        std::cout << "\n" << argv[1] << " occurrence: " << "\n" << displayContent1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "   ^" << "\n";

        std::cout << "\nDifference at " << argv[2] << " line " << line2 << ", column " << column2 << "\n";
        
        // Display 20 characters where the error occurred in file2
        std::string displayContent2 = displayDifferenceOccurrence(content2, firstDifference);
        std::cout << "\n" << argv[2] << " occurrence: " << "\n" << displayContent2 << "\n";
        std::cout << "   ^" << "\n";
    }

    // Close the files
    file1.close();
    file2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Current output of program if run:**

The contents of fileOne.txt and fileTwo.txt are different.

Difference at fileOne.txt line 1, column 51380251

fileOne.txt occurrence:

:%d42Hxh6)Iony37uEyRs$#b|LMUqX|'.b.Q5iS=}BfBY(j&_^2EkE[J29Xn

Difference at fileTwo.txt **line 1, column 51380251**

fileTwo.txt occurrence:

:%d42Hxh6)<<<<<<<Iony37uEyRs$#b|LMUqX|'.b.Q5iS=}BfBY(j&_^2Ek

**Expected output of program:**

The contents of fileOne.txt and fileTwo.txt are different.

Difference at fileOne.txt line 1, column 51380251

fileOne.txt occurrence:

:%d42Hxh6)Iony37uEyRs$#b|LMUqX|'.b.Q5iS=}BfBY(j&_^2EkE[J29Xn

Difference at fileTwo.txt **line 50, column 26**

fileTwo.txt occurrence:

:%d42Hxh6)<<<<<<<Iony37uEyRs$#b|LMUqX|'.b.Q5iS=}BfBY(j&_^2Ek

This program should compare two files for different issues in text. fileOne has all text on line 1 with no line spacing. fileTwo has line spacing and has the same code on multiple lines. I am trying to implement so the code can give me the correct line and column the issue was encountered. For fileTwo it should be on line 50 and column 26, So I can open the original file and find where the issue is located. But the program gets rid of the spacing which I need it to do to compare the program but outputs everything on line 1 when it should be on line 50. But I need to know where the issue is present in the original file. Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: `::isspace` returns true for all whitespace, including end-of-line characters `'\n'`. You are losing line information very early in the process when you call `removeSpaces`.

Comment: *For fileTwo it should be on line 50 and column 26* -- What you want to accomplish seems to be more sophisticated than a naive "remove all spaces and compare" approach.  Don't you need to store the line number and any other information, so that you can easily recall what line in the second file the text is on?  I think you need to draw out the proper data structure(s) needed for such a task before writing any code.

Comment: BTW, if you remove all spaces or condense the spaces, your column indices will no longer align between the two files.  Do you really need to remove the spaces or just ignore them?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can ignore the spaces. It's simply to check the text of two different files. Just not sure what is the most efficient way to go about it to get more information from the program.

Comment: Try reading entire line, then store it  in a variable, and remove spaces for comparison only (w/o changing file's content), track line and column number